# Imported functions depending on parameters from main python file

Tags: python, import, variable-assignment

I am a new user to Python, and I am mostly unfamiliar with imports. I've run into an issue where a function is defined in an imported python file, but its definition includes objects that were not defined in the imported file. Here is a minimum working example:

#### test1.py

```
def printL():
        print(L)
        return()
```

#### test2.py

```
import test1 as T1
L=10
T1.printL()
```

yields the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filepath/test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    T1.printL()
  File "filepath/test1.py", line 2, in printL
    print(L)
NameError: name 'L' is not defined
```

---

The example above is just illustrative. I was a little surprised, since the following function works just fine:

#### test3.py

```
def printL():
        print(L)
        return()
L=10
printL()
```

---

Why doesn't `test2.py` above work? It seems to be ignoring that I've assigned `L=10`.

Is there something I can do in `test2.py` to ensure that when it runs it will use the value `L=10` in `T1.printL()`? I'm imagining making some sort of copy of the function `printL()` or making variables global.

Comment: No.  If `printL` needs the value of `L`, then you need to pass it as a parameter.  Globals in Python are only global to a single file (which is why test2 doesn't work), and the best practice is to avoid them whenever possible.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks, if you write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that: L variable is defined in the file test2.py, so visible only in this file and the L variable in the body of printL function in test1.py is a local variable, visible only in this file too.

Try this instead

### test1.py

```
def printL(L):
    print(L)
    return()
```

### test2.py

```
import test1 as T1
L=10
T1.printL(L)
```

## Here is a best practice and more concise code:

### test.py

```
L = 10
print(L)
```

Comment: I believe you wanted `T1.print(L)`.